# Android Studio tries to load sources for sdk 26 when in fact my app is set to compile with 24

Tags: android, android-studio

I have my gradle set up to compile and target sdk 24

```
minSdkVersion = 21
targetSdkVersion = 24
buildToolsVersion = "24.0.3"
compileSdkVersion = 24
supportLibVersion = "24.2.1"
```

how ever when I try to go to the soure code for `AccountManager`, I get the error saying I dont have the source codes for sdk 26

[image]

how can I fix this?

just for the hell of it, I tried clicking on "Download", to download sources for sdk 26, but then I get an error saying that package is not available for download.

but the main issue is that its trying to load sdk 26 as opposed to sdk 24.

NOTE: this only happens for some of the Classes, others common Classes like View and Activityload just fine.

Comment: Check the IDE's project settings. Gradle itself should compile using those versions

Comment: @cricket_007 what should I check for in project settings

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was calling this class in a *submodule* of my app, and that submodule was using sdk 26.